# state_machines skip after transition callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

We use https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines gem on the project for states and I need to skip `after_transition` callback sometimes.

For example I have a class:

```
class Record
  after_transition on: :reject, do: :reject_callback

  private

  def reject_callback
    # some callback actions
  end
end
```

Is there any way to skip `reject_callback` on `reject` event, e.g. by passing some argument like `record.reject(skip_callback: true)` or something else, or this can be achieved only by creating new event without callback? I can to return `nil` in `reject_callback` by condition, but this approach is not suitable for me. I can't to use other gems for states, also.

Comment: Could the following be a good solution for you? Inside `reject_callback` you may put a guard clause `return unless need_callback?`.  You need to implement `need_callback?` method so that it returns `true` if you want the execution of the call back `false` otherwise.

Comment: @GiuseppeSchembri This is not suitable for me. I decided to create another event for this case.